# Titanium JS TextField Auto Height

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Is it possible to give a TextField in Titanium JS an "auto" height?

I'm using location services, which then fill a text field with the location data when a location is found. But it's always far too long and gets an ellipsis. I'd like the text field to scale in height to fit the text.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$.location.value = p.city + ", " + p.country;
$.location.height = Ti.UI.SIZE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text field does not grow automatically.You have to use the textarea for that purpose

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor: 'white'
});
var textArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: '#bbb',
  borderRadius: 5,
  color: '#888',
  font: {fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold'},
  keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
  returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_GO,
  textAlign: 'left',
  value: 'I am a textarea',
  height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
  top: 60,
  width: 300, 
});
win.add(textArea);
win.open()
```

Thanks

Comment: It didn't work. Does that mean it's not possible to do this with TextFields?

Comment: @Shrewbeans textField is for single line input only. You need texArea for multiple lines input or output